# View из системной таблицы PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть приложение, которое собирает данные из системных таблиц `postgresql 9.2`.
Нужна подробная информация из `pg_locks`.
В выводе этой этой таблицы нет явного признака, к какой БД относится информация о блокировках.
Как создать `view` с данными представления из `pg_locks`, включающую название базы данных?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_locks pl LEFT JOIN pg_stat_activity psa
    ON pl.pid = psa.pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

В [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/view-pg-locks.html) есть явный признак, к какой БД относится запись - поле `database`. Для вывода именно имени базы вам необходимо сделать `left join`  другой системной view `pg_database`.

```
select * from pg_locks l left join pg_database d on l.database = d.oid;
```

Нужен именно `left join`, т.к. `pg_locks.database` может содержать 0 для разделяемых объектов и `null` для `transaction ID`.

PS: `postgresql` 9.2 сильно устарел и больше не получает ни исправлений уязвимостей ни исправлений ошибок. Весьма рекомендую обновиться.

Comment: С этим запросом можно создать VIEW?

Comment: можно, отчего нет. Не припоминаю вообще ограничений на создание view к любым читающим запросам.

Comment: попробовала создать вьху. В итоге получаю, что в таблице по некоторым строчкам не везде отмечается название БД - из-за чего в приложении видно прочерк. Как сделать, чтобы название базы фигурировало в каждой строчке вывода этой вьюхи?

Comment: Я намеренно повторил указанные в мануале случаи, не имеющие отношения к какой-то конкретной базе. Если вы хотите эти блокировки просто пропустить и не учитывать - используйте inner join.